# Jquery focus and blur method

Tags: jquery

When I click on button the search input is in focus, but I want focus disappear on second click.
Here is my code:

// Search Button

```
  $("#mob-search-btn").click(function() {
  $(".search-container input").focus();
  });
```

I found this on w3 schools but I need this work only with one button.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_focus_blur_trigger

Hope to get help from you folks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check if the specified input has focus before deciding what to do:

Solution 1 (https://jsfiddle.net/azbnmuL9/3/):

```
( function($) {
  $('.search-container input').focus( function() {
    $(this).addClass('has-focus');
  });

  $( '#mob-search-btn' ).click( function() {
    var el = $( '.search-container input' );

    if(el.hasClass('has-focus')) {
      el.blur();
      el.removeClass('has-focus');
    } else {
      el.focus();
    }
  } );
} )(jQuery);
```

Drawback: Won't do you any good if you manually change focus to something else.

Solution 2 (https://jsfiddle.net/azbnmuL9/):

```
( function($) {
  $( '#mob-search-btn' ).mousedown( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $( '.search-container input' );

    if(el.is(':focus')) {
      el.blur();
    } else {
      el.focus();
    }
  } );
} )(jQuery);
```

Drawback: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the button from clicking (submitting the form or whatever).

Comment: This won't work because when you click the button, the button now has focus and when this code runs it will always be false

Comment: @ChrisBarr true, updating.

Answer (score 2):

You need to toggle the focus of input on every click. So a condition is required to check if the input is already focused.

```
var checkfocus = false;
$("#mob-search-btn").on('click', function()
{
    if(checkfocus){
        checkfocus = false;
        $("#mob-search-btn").blur();
    }
    else{
        checkfocus = true;
        $("#mob-search-btn").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but second and third "#mob-search-btn" should be ".search-container input"

Comment: @EvgheniLachi Yes right. My bad! Hope this has solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're saying, you want a single, same button that focuses on the first click and defocuses on the second click and so forth. To do that, simply store a control variable:

```
var focused = false;
$("#mob-search-btn").click(function()
{
  if (focused == true)
  {
    $(".search-container input").blur();
    focused = false;
  }
  else
  {
    $(".search-container input").focus();
    focused = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag to over come this use , focus event will not work for this scenario

```
let isFocus=false;

 $("#mob-search-btn").click(function() {

     if(isFocus){
      $(".search-container").blur();
      isFocus=false;
      }
      else{
      $(".search-container").focus();
      isFocus=true;
      }

  });
```

You can also use double click event to prevent this scenario if necessary

Comment: This works, but ".search-container" should be ".search-container input"

Comment: @EvgheniLachi - if "input" is needed then you can add it , not issues it will also work :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change when the input is blurred, you need to create a second click handler, e.g:

```
// Replace .my-button with your class or ID.
$(".my-button").click(function() {
    $(".search-container input").blur();
});
```

By the way, it's pretty much standard convention now to use `.on` rather than `.click`:

```
$(".my-button").on("click", function() {
    $(".search-container input").blur();
});
```